# Sqlite, DB clients & BLOB's: Practical DB Use

Tags: sqlite

I'm looking for an SQLite client that can help me to make practical use of the DB. The plan is to insert mp3's as BLOBs (or perhaps just as references to external files).  Each record will also include transcripts/notes/tags.

I'd like to be able to access this DB in such a way that I can click on the mp3 and listen to it, then add text data in the other fields, and finally search on text in the DB. LibreOffice Base is a nice client that allows me to define forms, but I'm not clear if simple access to the mp3 is possible. Are there other options?

I should say up front that I can do bash scripting and C, but I don't have python.

Comment: If you don't get much traction here, you might move the Q to dba.sx or softwarerecs.sx

Comment: Thanks, Jeff.  I looked at DBA, but those guys look like uber pros!  I was kind of scared off ...

Comment: If you want to "click", perhaps you could consider a web browser and a simple PHP or perl app, or from bash, a number of scripts to list, search and manipulate your database and/or play your music. I'd go for the second. What do you think?

Comment: @ZiggyCrueltyfreeZeitgeister - Thanks man.  Since I don't have PHP or perl either, I'd have to go with the bash scripts.  Thing is, I'm just very surprised that a more straightforward solution isn't available.  I mean, this isn't the 1980's. We're well into the age of computers already!

Comment: Is there a reason why you wouldn't use xmms/winamp (or similar) that are designed for this very purpose? Why would you consider something so complicated as connecting LibreOffice Base to sqlite instead?

Comment: @ziggy. These are mp3's of voice messages DL'd from google voice with the transcript, to which I'll add notes & tags.  So I need a way to insert all this into the DB.  That means using say awk to create a bunch of insert statements ...

Comment: I get that, but why is it that you prefer doing that rather than using XMMS? You can add tags and notes directly into the MP3 files.

Comment: @Ziggy - Ok, I'm guessing you mean either Audacious or XMMS2 or maybe BMPx, the various forks/rewrites of XMMS - and if you're telling me that there's a cli for inserting data and that there's a good search language so I can search the text, then ...  Maybe that is a  solution.  (I'm going to look now, though I did take a look at XMMS2 a year ago and didn't really grok it.)

Comment: Here's a QA with plenty of resources and alternatives for reading and manipulating mp3 tags from the command line: http://askubuntu.com/q/226773/533244. You can use your bash skills to manipulate those mp3 as if it was a database!

Comment: @Ziggy - I see!  This is a surprise.  The metadata format, [ID3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3), has a user-defined text information frame (TXXX).  I could dump the transcript/notes/tags into there using a cli tag editor, and use other cli commands to retrieve/search/sort.  Or maybe just XMMS2 would provide that.  Ok!  I had no idea that mp3's had room for this kind of stuff.  Thank you for pointing it out.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on the comments, one option to simplify this requirement without resorting to developing a user interface to link sound files and a database, and considering your skills in shell programming, is using command line tools to edit/retrieve tags on MP3 files ([Here's a QA with plenty of resources and alternatives for reading and manipulating mp3 tags from the command line](https://askubuntu.com/q/226773/533244)), and using XMMS2 or similar to build and maintain the library of files, and see or manually edit individual file's MP3 tags.

The benefit of this approach is that XMMS2 is not only very good at handling a library of sounds/music (including creating playlists and so forth) but also in editing MP3 tags, which can be manipulated from command line scripts through a variety of open source well documented and popular tools.